# html signature outlook

Tags: html, outlook, signature

We have a new company signature which I have to edit manually. Well I copied the code from an email plus picture and changed the path. But for some reason I am unable to change the y-position of the picture. I want the picture to be at the top.

Here is the code for the display of the picture:

```
<v:shapetype 
id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" 
 o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" 
 stroked="f">
 <v:stroke joinstyle="miter" />
 <v:formulas>
  <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0" />
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0" />
  <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight" />
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth" />
  <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0" />
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight" />
  <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0" />
 </v:formulas>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect" />
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t" />
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_0" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" 
 alt="picturename.png" 
 href="someurl/screenshot.jpg" 
 style='position:absolute;margin-left:295.9pt;margin-top:3.8pt;width:147.8pt;
 height:45.25pt;z-index:1;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;
 mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;
 mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;
 mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;
 mso-position-vertical-relative:text' o:button="t">
 <v:fill o:detectmouseclick="t" />
 <v:imagedata src="userpath/siglogo.jpg" o:title="picturename" />
</v:shape>
```

Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used the sourcecode again and adjusted the paths. No repositioning necessary :-)

Comment: do you know if it's possible to edit the signature images to use '%' rather than pt? My boss wants the images to be responsive but it really doesn't like using a percentage for the width